# Asp.net Telerik MVC 4 Application with Unit Test Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a Asp.net Telerik MVC 4 Application that has a unit project in it. When I tried to initialize a user object in the unit test, it failed. It gave an error message that said the connection string does not exist in the config file. However, I check the config file, and the connection string is there.

here are some sample codes:

//Connection String

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="KMSSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.KMSSEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.KMSSEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.KMSSEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=KMSS;persist security info=True;user id=******;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

//Initialize my Context
 private KMSSEntities entity = new KMSSEntities();

 //This is my insert user
 public void InsertUser(User user)
        {
            entity.Users.Add(user);
        } 

//this is code in the test method

    User u = new User();
                u.UserName = "test";
                u.password = "Password";
                u.FirstName = "first";
                u.LastName = "Last";

                StudentRepository rep = new StudentRepository(new KMSSEntities());
                rep.InsertUser(u);  **//This is where it's returning the error message**
                rep.Save();
```

//This is the stack trace.

```
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at KMSS.Models.UserRepository.InsertUser(User user) in c:\com\KMSS\KMSS\KMSS\Models\UserRepository.cs:line 29
   at KMSSTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\com\KMSS\KMSS\KMSSTests\UnitTest1.cs:line 21
```

Comment: Does this configuration is in your App.config within the test project . Also a side note : Since you accessing a configuration, this is not a Unit Test.

Comment: @Raj Yes, it is in my App.config file. Should I use a Mock object instead of accessing a real database?

Comment: @josianferiice I think in this case you should use the real database. You are testing the repository type method so the integration test is much suite for the purpose. When you debug it, put a breakpoint where the connection string set. See whether you can connect to the database using that connection string. Also check for any incorrect mappings you may have. Does you real app connect to the DB successfully using the same code?

Comment: @Raj, I removed the unit test project and test it in the about controller. I was able to connect and retrieve data without issue.

Comment: So it is likely a configuration issue in your test project.